# Submit Form using Button in Parent Component in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, reactjs, web

[image: form modal]

So I have to implement a form in modal, as you can see, the button in the modal are not the buttons in the form. I created the form as a child component of the modal. How can I submit the form using the button in the parent component. I am using [React Semantic-UI](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form#form-example-capture-values) react as my UI framework.

I think if I can hide the button in the form and trigger it using JavaScript. I think this might be achieved via getElementById, but is there a react way of doing it?

My current Modal looks like this:

```
<Modal open={this.props.open} onClose={this.props.onClose} size="small" dimmer={"blurring"}>
    <Modal.Header> Edit Activity {this.props.name} </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Content>
      <ActivityInfoForm/>
    </Modal.Content>
    <Modal.Actions>
        <Button negative onClick={this.props.onClose}>
            Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button positive
                content='Submit'
                onClick={this.makeActivityInfoUpdateHandler(this.props.activityId)} />
    </Modal.Actions>
</Modal>
```

My form code looks like this:

```
<Form>
    <Form.Group widths='equal'>
        <Form.Input label='Activity Name' placeholder='eg. CIS 422' />
        <Form.Input label='Activity End Date' placeholder='Pick a Date' />
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group widths='equal'>
        <Form.Input label='Total Capacity' placeholder='eg. 30' />
        <Form.Input label='Team Capacity' placeholder='eg. 3' />
    </Form.Group>
</Form>
```

Comment: if you want to do it the react way, you should store the input values somewhere(e.g `state`,`redux-form`) so you can get them later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What does your `makeActivityInfoUpdateHandler` function look like?

I assume you did it by the following way, and just continue adding more code to make it work for you:

1/ Add `ref` to your Form, then you can access the Form in the parent (Modal):

```
<Modal>

    <Modal.Content>
        <ActivityInfoForm ref="activityForm" />
    </Modal.Content>

</Modal>
```

2/ Then in the `makeActivityInfoUpdateHandler` function:

```
makeActivityInfoUpdateHandler = (activityId) => {
    // ...
    this.refs.activityForm.getWrappedInstance().submit();
    // ...

}
```

The above code is the way you should do, please post here some more details in case this doesn't work yet!

===========
**EDITED VERSION BELOW**: (*after discussion with the author, and we together found a good way around!*):

The idea now is put the `ref` on a button (this button has `type="submit"`, and it belongs to the form), then when the button outside is clicked, we just need to call the "`click()`" function of the `ref` button [which is a smart thinking from the author himself]

(*Actually,  component from semantic-ui is a modified and improved version, no longer the standard form, so my previous way above may not work when it tries to submit the form, however, the below way will work*)

The code will now look like:

1/ Add `ref` to the button on the form:

```
<Form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit} >
    <button style={{}} type='submit' ref={ (button) => { this.activityFormButton = button } } >Submit</button>
</Form>
```

2/ Then in the `makeActivityInfoUpdateHandler` function, trigger `click()` of the above button:

```
makeActivityInfoUpdateHandler = (activityId) => {
    // ...
    this.activityFormButton.click();
    // ...

}
```

Comment: That function is really just a skeleton function awaiting to be filled.

Comment: that does not seem to be working, does not give me any errors either, they <Form> is actually a component in Semantic UI React can be found here https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form#form-example-form

Comment: Seems so..actually I guess Semantic UI React handle their form differently, I will try another way and update the previous answer shortly, please hold on

Comment: However, which action will be executed when the form is submitted? Do you have handleSubmit() function for your Form component? If yes, can you console.log and see some values in your submitted form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144621/discussion-between-thinhvo0108-and-rui).

Answer (score 35):

The simplest solution would be to use [HTML form Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form.asp)

Add "id" attribute to your form: id='my-form'

```
<Form id='my-form'>
                    <Form.Group widths='equal'>
                        <Form.Input label='Activity Name' placeholder='eg. CIS 422' />
                        <Form.Input label='Activity End Date' placeholder='Pick a Date' />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group widths='equal'>
                        <Form.Input label='Total Capacity' placeholder='eg. 30' />
                        <Form.Input label='Team Capacity' placeholder='eg. 3' />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form>
```

Add the appropriate "form" attribute to the needed button outside of the form: form='my-form'

```
<Button positive form='my-form' content='Submit' value='Submit'  />
```

Comment: Nice elegant solution +1

Comment: I had to set button type='submit' for this to work, nice find!

Comment: Best solution IMO

Comment: The owner should accept this answer as the right one. Thanks Pavlo!

Comment: I was wondering: what is the 'positive' attribute in the Button component ?

Comment: @Nayte - just for button style, part of the Semantic-UI framework, https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/button/#variations-positive

Comment: Can we embed submission of multiple form using single button??

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer was useful. But the method in it doesn't seem to work any longer. Here's how I went about it.

You can give a ref to the child component when it is being created.

```
<ChildComponent ref={this.childComponent}/>
```

And use it in the button's onClick method. (This is the code for the button)

```
<Button variant= "light" onClick={this.onClick}>  
    Submit
</Button>
```

(This is the onClick method)

```
onClick = (event) => {
    this.childComponent.current.handleSubmit(event);
}
```

I'm calling a method in the child component called handleSubmit. It can look like this.

```
handleSubmit = (event)=> {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Your code here. For example,
    alert("Form submitted");  
}
```

Comment: That's smart but I add a detail : 
Don't forget in constructor  `this.childComponent = React.createRef();` if you use a class component.