# Form is not submitting from an outer button using react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

```
 class Index extends React.Component {
    state = {isLoading: false}

    onSubmit = (event) => {
       console.log('here we go');
       event.preventDefault();
       // this.checkEmailExistance();
    };

    render() {
      return (
       <>
         <form id="myForm" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} noValidate>
            <CredentialsInputs />
         </form>
         <footer>
            <Button type="submit" form="myForm" isPrimary isDisabled={!isValid}>   
               Continue
            </Button>
          </footer>
        </>
     )}
 }
```

`onSubmit` function is not invoked

> Note: the props (type and form) was passed well and check using the console elements

Is the problem something related to react?

Comment: And it's a bound function?

Comment: @rrd You don't need to bind as it's a fat arrow function. Also, logging to console doesn't need binding.

Comment: Have you got the `onSubmit` inside `render()` or outside `render()`? Can you show the full function, please?

Comment: Move the onSubmit={this.onSubmit} to the button's onClick handler, does it invoke then?

Comment: Your form has a lot of issues: Example, `id=myForm"` doesn't have a starting `"`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577141/how-to-submit-form-from-a-button-outside-that-component-in-react look this answer

Comment: @DostonbekOripjonov just checked it,, But what is the purpose usage of the form? it's hacky way!

Comment: The way you want use is also hacky bro. Officially, submit button should be located between form tags

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `ref` to the form, and then in the "Button onClick", you do ref.submit().

In that situation, you set an `id` to the form... So, if you want to make a really really ugly implementation, you could do something like `document.getElementByid('myForm').submit()`

If you want to do something better, you should do something like...

```
<form ref={ref => this.formRef = ref} ...
```

```
<button onClick={() => this.formRef.submit()}
```

Still... not super beautiful. I would recommend Hooks + useRef.

Answer (score -1):

You have written you submit button outside of form. You should move your submit button inside of form,

```
<form id="myForm" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} noValidate>
     <CredentialsInputs />
     <footer>
         <Button type="submit" form="myForm" isPrimary isDisabled={!isValid}>
           Continue
         </Button>
     </footer>    
</form>
```

If you don't want to move `footer` inside of form, then you should have `onClick` on your `Button`

```
<form id="myForm" noValidate>
     <CredentialsInputs />
</form> 

<footer>
    <Button type="submit" form="myForm" isPrimary isDisabled={!isValid} onClick={this.onSubmit}>
        Continue
    </Button>
</footer>
```

Comment: My purpose is how to submit a form bu outside button, is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Put the button inside form. it will work.

> You should always include a button element inside form to trigger onSubmit method automatic, Else you can call the method manually with onClick event of the button.